# Python Kivy Adding a Slider in a TreeView

Tags: python, slider, treeview, kivy

I tried adding a slider to a treeview like this:

```
myTreeView = TreeView()
myTreeView.add_node(Slider(min=0, max = 20, value = 0))
```

But this generates and error 'The node must be a subclass of TreeViewNode'
How can i add a slider to a treeview in kivy?

Comment: Hi @Baz if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PalimPalim it really helped!. I am pretty new to stackoverflow so i don't know what you mean by "accepting" your answer

Comment: Accepting means, activating the checkmark on the left of my answer, so it becomes green. Upvoting is cklicking the up arrow on the left of my answer. Both will give reputation to me. Accepting will also give reputation to you. It shows that you like an answer (upvoting) or that it solved your problem (accepting) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `TreeViewSlider` by extending `Slider` and `TreeViewNode`.

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    pass
class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass
class TreeViewSlider(Slider, TreeViewNode):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        tv = TreeView()
        tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My first item'))
        tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My second item'))
        tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text='My third item'))
        tv.add_node(TreeViewSlider())
        return tv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```